# Illegal start of expression error in java swing auto-generated code

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am using Java Swing to create a GUI.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import java.lang.Process;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

It is telling me that the line " private void outputDirActionPerformed..." has an illegal start of expression, however that line of code is autogenerated by NetBeans. commandPLINK is an array of parameters, and is behaving correctly.

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandPLINK);

    try {
        pb.inheritIO();
        Process p = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(rtPCRGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}   //convertButtonActionPerformed                                          

private void outputDirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Any idea what might be happening that's causing the autogenerated code to throw this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens when you are missing a `}` somewhere **before** the line that triggers the error. You should look at the preceding method and see if every `{` is matched with a corresponding `}`.

Also, you may look if there is an extra `}` after the generated method.

To be more clear, this error means that the compiler did not expect to have a function definition starting there, because it is believing that you are still in a method block, and a method can not be inside another method.